# Impact Disabling "Update Root Certificates" Has On SQL Server

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, certificate

I was told that Disabling the `Update Root Certificates` option from the `Windows Components` section of `Add/Remove Programs` will cause SQL Server to stop working properly.

It this correct, or is my friend simply misinformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my friend was referring to [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926839/). Luckily for us, this is only an issue if you are running Windows Server 2003 SP1. Since we've installed SP2, we are not affected by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could see how this would prevent the checking of the list of trusted certificate authorities in the Windows update website.  If your application was requiring SQL Server to use certificates (Service broker certificate authentication?) I could see this being an issue.  Perhaps something like this is your friend's point of reference.